# Taxonomize taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I want to [register taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) that apply to [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) terms (in addition to posts). [I believe this is possible](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) because posts and terms are both WP objects. What steps are needed to achieve this? Because taxos are mainly geared towards posts, what needs to be done differently to achieve this? On "edit term" pages, how can I get the editing boxes to appear like they do in posts?

Relevant core files:

- [wp-includes/taxonomy.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php)
- [wp-admin/edit-tag-form.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/edit-tag-form.php)

Answer (score 1):

Terms and posts are both WP Objects, but different ones.

They are stored in different database tables, so...
... they don't have unique IDs (term and post can have same ID), so...
... they're IDs cannot be both used as foreign key in database, so...
... I don't think it's possible (well, maybe it is, but it won't be as easy as you think it is).

Comment: It's not easy, but it should be. The unique IDs are an issue. There must be a way. Maybe an intermediary private post type could be used as a map. See related tickets [10142](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10142) and  [14513](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14513)